# AddHandler event on dynamic button, incorrect instance properties in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, class, methods, event-handling

I'm new to custom classes. I have a class called 'game'. In the class, I have a method called 'addGame()' that creates a dynamic picture box called 'pBox'. After creating the control, I'm doing the following to register a click event:

```
AddHandler pBox.Click, AddressOf Me.launchGame
```

And here is launchGame:

```
Public Sub launchGame()
    MsgBox(Me.name)
End Sub
```

The problem is, "Me.name" is always the most recently added instances name, not the one I clicked on.

---

Based on a suggestion, I also tried this:

```
Public Sub launchGame(ByVal sender As Object)
    MsgBox(sender.name)
End Sub
```

But now "**AddHandler pBox.Click, AddressOf Me.launchGame**" says

> Method 'Public Sub launchGame(sender As Object)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'

And "**AddHandler pBox.Click, AddressOf Me.launchGame(Me)**" says

> AddressOf operand must be the name of a method without parentheses

---

```
Public Sub launchGame(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal sender as EventArgs)
    MsgBox(sender.name)
End Sub
```

Now no errors, but the msgBox is blank.

Comment: Have you tried adding a parameter ByVal sender as Object and then doing sender.name?

Comment: "AddressOf must be the name of a method without parentheses" and if I add ByVal sender to launchgame, then it wants me to pass an object.  Catch 22 or something :)

Comment: I'm glad you did the edit! The first error is only saying that you also need to add ByVal e as System.EventArgs - just don't put anything after the Me.LaunchGame for the AddressOf

Comment: hmm, okay, now the msgBox is blank...

Comment: And pBox has a name, right? Or are you trying to get the name of the game class instance?

Comment: The name of the game class instance.  So when I click on the picture (pBox) it just shows me the game name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20367/discussion-between-david-brunow-and-scott-beeson)

Comment: In your project properties, or at the top of your code, make sure that you have turned Option Strict On

Comment: @David, if you want to post a generic answer I'd love to accept it and give you the points for taking the time to chat with me.

Comment: Function "launchGame" has two parameters with the same name. Does that even compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that pBox was always the most recent pictureBox control. I created a control Array based on *[Creating Control Arrays in Visual Basic .NET and Visual C# .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

Now I do the AddHandler in the AddNewpBox() method of my pBoxArray class.
I also created a list to handle the "game" class, as suggested by David Brunow. Then I'm setting the pictureBox "Tag" property to the index of the game in the "games" array.

So now my click handler looks like the following, and it seems to work great.

```
Public Sub pBoxClick(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox(games(sender.tag).name)
End Sub
```